# Google Oauth Cross-client auth with javascript: Token has expired

Tags: javascript, php, oauth, google-api-php-client

I've been dealing all day with this problem and I just can't figure out what's wrong.

I have an application using the Google Api client for javascript which is working with no problems. Now I want to do something on the server side, so after researching for a bit, found that the way to go would be to use the token on the client side with `setAccessToken` method in the backend.

So I try sending my token object as JSON (using `JSON.stringify(gapi.auth.getToken())` ) and once I try doing an API call on the backend that requires auth, I get the following error:

> The OAuth 2.0 access token has expired, and a refresh token is not available. Refresh tokens are not returned for responses that were auto-approved.

So, a little puzzled, I try veryfing the token using curl on google's endpoint, which returns the following

```
{
    "issued_to": "client_id",
    "audience": "client_id",
    "user_id": "user_id",
    "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me",
    "expires_in": 1465,
    "email": "user_email",
    "verified_email": true,
    "access_type": "online"
}
```

So I know the token is fine and valid. The way my code is setup is as follows (redacted for:

```
<?php
// The token JSON is not inline, it comes from another source directly from the client side, but this is how it looks
$token_json = '{"state":"","access_token":"TOTALLY_VALID_ACCESS_TOKEN","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":"3600","scope":"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me","client_id":"CLIENT_ID","g_user_cookie_policy":"single_host_origin","cookie_policy":"single_host_origin","response_type":"token","issued_at":"1415583001","expires_at":"1415586601","g-oauth-window":{},"status":{"google_logged_in":false,"signed_in":true,"method":"PROMPT"}}';

$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = 'CLIENT_ID';
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = 'CLIENT_SECRET';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setAccessToken($token_json);

$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

try{

    /* Random code goes here */

    // Auth Exception here.
    $insertRequest = $youtube->videos->insert("status,snippet", $video);

} catch (Google_Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
}
```

Do I need to set up offline access or something? I have the requirement that the login process must be in javascript, so no chance of recreating the login flow from the backend.

Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if someone else stumbles into this:

Apparently, sharing tokens directly is not the way to go, since the different API wrappers handle tokens differently. What you have to do is pass the one-time code to PHP and use the following to acquire an access token

```
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
    $client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);

    // Couldn't find this anywhere in the docs, but it's required. If you don't pass this, you will get an Origin Mismatch error.
    $client->setRedirectUri('postmessage'); 

    // Get this from javascript
    $client->authenticate($ONE_TIME_CODE);

    // Optionally, you might want to retrieve the token and save it somewhere else e.g. the session, as the code is only good for a single use.         
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
```

Also, from JS you NEED to specify you require this one-time code besides the JS token, which I couldn't find documented anywhere else as well.

Example settings, for gapi.auth.authorize

```
{
        client_id: CLIENT_ID
        scope: APP_SCOPES
        cookie_policy: 'single_host_origin'
        response_type: 'code token'
        immediate: true
}
```

Comment: Using "postmessage" as the redirect URL was the key piece of information for me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, Moustached. I've also spent the whole day trying to solve that. However, I found not that obvious what is one-time code and how to get it, so I decided to provide my code here in case someone else face the same problem:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=onGoogleAPILoad" async defer></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var auth2;

                window.onGoogleAPILoad = function() {
                    gapi.load('auth2', function() {
                        auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({ client_id: 'CLIENT_ID', scope: 'profile' });
                    });
                };

                $('button').on('click', function() {
                    auth2.grantOfflineAccess({'redirect_uri': 'postmessage'}).then(function(response) {
                        $.ajax({
                            method: 'POST',
                            url: '/auth/signin',
                            success: onAuthSuccess = function(response) {
                                // check response from your server and reload page if succeed
                            },
                            data: { code: response.code }
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button>Sign In</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

and for back-end the code is almost the same:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId('CLIENT_ID');
$client->setClientSecret('CLIENT_SECRET');
$client->setRedirectUri('postmessage'); 

$client->authenticate($code); // here is one-time code

$plus = new Google_Service_Plus($client);
$user = $plus->people->get('me');
// $user is in array, containing now id, name, etc.
```

Here is an [article](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow) on that topic.